# What is a "Melee Spell Attack" and how does it differ from a regular spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack

In 5e a lot of the spells in both the Monster Manual and PHB talk about a spell being a "melee spell attack". Is this simply to do with the range of the spell or are there additional rules to rolling?

The reason I'm slightly confused is because the cantrip *Thorn Whip* says to make a melee spell attack against a foe, but it has a range of 30.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A melee spell attack follows all the rules of a traditional melee attack. The applicable rules are on page 195/205 of the PHB or 73/81 in the Basic Rules pdf.

> Most creatures have a 5-foot reach and can thus attack targets within
>   5 feet of them when making a melee attack. Certain creatures
>   (typically those larger than Medium) have melee attacks with a greater
>   reach than 5 feet, as noted in their descriptions.

In this case, thorn whip attacks like a melee weapon with 30-foot reach.

The difference between a melee attack and ranged attack is that a ranged attack suffers disadvantage if you're within 5 feet of an enemy while a melee attack is not affected.

In addition, a melee spell attack like a ranged spell attack uses your spell attack modifier (spellcasting ability + proficiency).

Comment: Wait, does this mean that spells that call for a melee spell attack can be used to take opportunity attacks? That's only about 5 spells, but still...

Comment: Only if you have the Warcaster feat.

Comment: There is one other difference: a Melee _Spell_ Attack, as opposed to a Melee _Weapon_ Attack, uses your Spell Attack Modifier (spellcasting ability modifier + proficiency modifier).

Comment: Another difference is that melee attacks have advantage on prone targets.

Comment: @enkryptor - that's not quite true.  Attacks from within 5' of the prone target have advantage, any attacks from more than 5' away will have disadvantage.  This also means that ranged attacks against a prone target within 5' will be a straight roll - advantage and disadvantage cancelling (unless they're also incapacitated).

Comment: @sirjonsnow this is correct. It seems using a pike would impose disadvantage, despite the melee attack.

Answer (score 13):

This works like any other spell attack roll; it uses your spellcasting attribute and so on. However, it also has the properties of a melee attack.

Notably, ranged attacks (including ranged spell attacks) are made with disadvantage if you're within 5 feet of an active enemy. "Thorn Whip" and other melee spells can be used in melee without disadvantage.